# jQuery CSS Targeting data-title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently have this code, and am wanting to bold and green the text via CSS whenever the shipping is free, but not sure where i am going wrong with jQuery?

`<script>
$("td[data-title='Shipping']").contains('Free').css('color', 'green');
</script>`

`<td data-title="Shipping">
FREE EXPRESS SHIPPING!
</td>`

`<td data-title="Shipping">
$4.99 
</td>`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery instances (`$() => jQuery instance`) do not have `.contains` method. You should use the [`contains` as a selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("td[data-title='Shipping']:contains('Free')").css('color', 'green');
```

jQuery constructor has a [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method but it's used for a different purpose.

Comment: Hmmm.. doesn't seem to be working ? 

[Click here for the test page](http://www.hardtunedstore.com/test.html)

Comment: @LozGlen Your code is executed too soon. Either move the script from the `head` to the end of the `body` element or use the `$().ready` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses!

Seems to be fixed it on the test page, but it seems to be having problems on the live checkout page... 

The cart area is AJAX driven, am guessing it doesn't play nice with AJAX built areas of the page? 
Any recommended workarounds there?

Answer (score 0):

try change the script into this one:

```
<script>
    $('td[data-title="Shipping"]:contains(Free)').css('color', 'green');
</script>
```

Above script only change color for the first `td` only, since the last `td` does not contain `Free` text.

if you want to change both of them, try change the `tr` instead:

```
<script>
    $('td[data-title="Shipping"]:contains(Free)').parents('tr').css('color', 'green');
</script>
```